# Обработка бинарного файла, с++

Tags: c++

Допустим, у меня есть бинарный файл, в котором хранятся данные типа int.
Как реверсировать значения относительно центра через fseek, fread и fwrite?
Я уже сделал ввод, пытаюсь додумать цикл для этих действий замены, но до меня попросту не доходит.
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <conio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <iostream.h>
    #include <math.h>

```
void main()
{
FILE *f;
char fn[1000], s[1000], *p;
int *l,d;
int n;
double o;
float si=0;
double two=2;
printf ("Binary file : ");
scanf ("%s", fn);
f=fopen(fn,"w+b");
if (f==NULL)
{
printf("ERROR");
getch();
}
printf("\nyour binary length of file: ");
scanf("%i",&d);
fwrite(&d, sizeof(int), 1, f);
l=new int[d];
for (int i=0;i<d;i++)
{
printf("Enter your %i element of binary file : ", i+1);
scanf("%d",l);    //vvod stroki
fwrite(&l,sizeof(int),1,f);
}
```

Comment: Если файл не гигантский, то проще считать его целиком в массив интов, поменять в нём значения местами и записать обратно одним блоком. Если очень большой - всё равно представьте, что это массив интов. Только вместо обращения по индексу (`a[i]`) вы ставите файловый указатель в нужную позицию (`fseek(f, i*sizeof(int), SEEK_SET)`) и читаете/записываете значения.

P.S. Какое отношение к тому что вы хотите имеет ваш код - непонятно. 

P.P.S. И при чём тут C++?

Comment: Предлагаю компромиссный вариант: читать в два одинаковых буфера (массива) с начала и с конца файла, каждый переворачивать и записывать наоборот (первый в конец, второй в начало). Главное не пропустить середину. fseek с параметром SEEK_END и ftell в помощь.
А представленный код действительно к вопросу имеет очень отдаленное отношение. Думаю, @eamirus не совсем различает C и C++.